# siunitx forced scientific notation

Tags: siunitx

In the next case the scientific notation is useless, except to show it exists in this case too, regarding to its defintion.

How to achieve this exemple :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num[scientific-notation=true]{3.14159e0}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, ok, that is you opinion, but what is your question? Do you want to know, how to switch it off, or what is your aim?

Comment: What is my opinion? Sorry for my poor english. I want the 10^0 even if it is useless in this case, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my fault that I did not get the question. But nevertheless, you got the right answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the right option is

```
\num[retain-zero-exponent=true]{3.14159e0}
```